# NSData doesn't get the image from image url

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

```
NSString *imgvalue=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:item.imgItem];
printf("\n img1 value is %s",[imgvalue UTF8String]);

cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.jpg"];
if (imgvalue !=nil) 
{
    NSData *imageData;
    @try 
    {
        printf("\n image value in image data is %s",[imgvalue UTF8String]);
        imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgvalue]];
        printf("\n imageData Length is %d",[imageData length]);
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) 
    {
        //printf("Exception message is %s",[e);
    }
    @finally 
    {
        UIImage * imageFromImageData = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        //[image setImage:imageFromImageData];
        cell.imageView.image=imageFromImageData;
        [imageData release];
        [imageFromImageData release];
    }   
}
```

After getting the imgValue I copied that url and when I checked in the browser it shows me the image but it didn't store into NSData.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and everything seems to be working.
Please check imageData with 
`NSLog(@"%u", [imageData length]);`

Comment: Thank U for ur reply surfrider i will check it..!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
NSString *imgvalue=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:item.imgItem];
```

to

```
NSString *imgvalue=@"http://animals.catchsmile.com/cat-3/";
```

using this i got data in log..
i have used static string and tested you can use item.imgItem value as well..